# Updating my progressbar while processing

Tags: java, swing, progress-bar, event-dispatch-thread

I'm building in Java  a small app that basically check each line in some pasted text for postal adresses, and check their localisation in a database.

It all works fine, but the checking process can take a long time, and I want to add a progress bar to update its value every time a line is checked.

Despite reading other threads on this subject, I don't understand why my progress bar only updates when the process is over.
I gathered that I need to separate my progress bar from my process in some way that doesn't freeze the GUI, but I would really apreciate some help and explaining as how to do it, and why. So thanks in advance to whoever can help !

Here is the main code, and the process which progress I want to update in the progress bar is the one launched by the button2 listener.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.IOException;

import static sun.security.krb5.Confounder.intValue;

public class mainform {
private JButton button1;
private JTextField txt_1;
private JPanel panelmain;
private JLabel outlab;
private JTextField codepostal;
private JTextArea paste_lignes;
private JButton button2;
private JProgressBar progressBar1;
private JLabel progress;




public mainform() {

    button2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            String[] lines = paste_lignes.getText().split("\\n");
            String resultQPV = "";
            int numLines = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
                numLines++;
            }

            System.out.println(numLines);

            for (int i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
                String adresse = "";
                String CP = "";
                String[] cells = lines[i].split("\\t");
                float percent_d = ((float) i / (float) numLines) * 100;
                System.out.println(i + " " + numLines + " " + percent_d);
                int percent = (int) percent_d;

                progressBar1.setValue(percent);


                try {
                    Thread.sleep(50);
                } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }


                for (int j = 0; j < cells.length; j++) {

                    if (CheckAdresse.identify_me(cells[j]) == "CP") {
                        CP = cells[j];
                    }

                    if (CheckAdresse.identify_me(cells[j]) == "adresse") {
                        adresse = cells[j];
                    }

                }


                String QPV = null;
                String voie = null;
                String numero = null;

                if (adresse == "" || CP == "") {
                    QPV = "erreur sur la ligne";
                } else {
                    voie = ParserAdresse.voie(adresse);
                    numero = Integer.toString(ParserAdresse.numVoie(adresse));
                    try {
                        QPV = CheckAdresse.Check(CP, voie, numero);
                    } catch (IOException e1) {
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }


                resultQPV = resultQPV + QPV + "\n";


                //System.out.println(i + " " + percent + " " + voie + " " + CP + " " + numero);

            }

            paste_lignes.setText(resultQPV);


        }
    });
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("mainform");
    frame.setContentPane(new mainform().panelmain);
    frame.setSize(900, 400);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);

}
```

}

Comment: the below link may help you [Example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5691979/progressbar-doesnt-change-its-value-in-java?rq=1)

Comment: That did the trick ! Thank you for this link, the solution in the referenced thread worked for me !

Answer (score 0):

It's because want two actions but run it only in one thread. So they need to share the execution and can't work paralell. 
What you need is run your progressbar in separate thread. 
So you will have

- One thread for application
- One thread for progress bar

How to use threads in java you can read here https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/runthread.html